# How to delete parts of data source?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to remove a value or values from a data source by patching, i.e. not by resending the whole data. I can do that by patching with a slice. For example, if I want to remove the first value of

```
data = dict(x=list(range(1,5)), y=list(range(6,10)))
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
print(source.data)
```

> {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [6, 7, 8, 9]}

I can use

```
source.patch(dict(x=[(slice(0,2),[2])], y=[(slice(0,2),[7])]))
print(source.data)
```

> {'x': [2, 3, 4], 'y': [7, 8, 9]}

This requires me to know the previous or next value depending on where I want to delete. How would you delete an index / a range of indices from all columns? Is this the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

The `patch` method can only be used to update existing values to new values, i.e. it cannot be used to change the size of columns. In fact what you have above, where the new data is smaller than the slice length, should really raise a `RuntimeError`, and I am surprised it does not.

There is no way to *delete* data out of a CDS column except to re-send the entire column. This is because on the JavaScript side, the typed arrays in the browser do not support all the fancy slicing and indexing that is available on the Python side in Numpy, etc.

Depending on you specific situation, there may be more or less hacky workarounds, e.g. perhaps you could patch values you want to "delete" to be NaNs. But that's not something that would always "work" (e.g. it would behave badly with lines).

Comment: interesting and unexpected answer. i haven't tested it with a bokeh server yet.